# Removing an equal object from array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of colors. I want to remove one which is equal to another object.

Array

```
[
    { id: 1, color: "red"},
    { id: 2, color: "blue"},
]
```

Object

```
{ id: 2, color: "blue" }
```

I do not know the `index` in the array. Ideally, it could be something like `array.remove(object)`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What indicates two objects being "equal"? Do both the `id` and `color` properties have to match or only the `color`?

Comment: Both is better but one will suffice in this scenario

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove specific element from an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/remove-specific-element-from-an-array)

Comment: @KeluThatsall Uhh, think you have the wrong link? That just links back to this question.

Comment: Ye I just noticed too :P

Comment: You'll have to iterate over the array, find the item you want to remove and remove it.

Comment: _"Both is better but one will suffice in this scenario"_ - In the example you give there is no match on both properties, just on id.

Comment: No it's not matching on id, but on color. If you want I can rewrite it as an answer...

Comment: @nnnnnn Aha... I just fixed that

Comment: @Pixark they will still not match, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EhmLK/). JS won't perform "deep check" for all properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming "equal" means "having the same id", you just need a loop and an if test:

```
function removeItem(array, item) {
    for (var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        if (array[i].id === item.id) {
            array.splice(i, 1);
            break; // remove this line if there could be multiple matching elements
        }
}

var array = [
        { id: 1, color: "red"},
        { id: 2, color: "blue"},
    ];
removeItem(array, { id: 2, color : "blue"});
```

Obviously you can extend this to test both properties:

```
        if (array[i].id === item.id && array[i].color === item.color) {
```

If you wanted to be able to compare arbitrary objects with unknown property names then instead of a simple `if` test you could use a nested `for..in` loop to test each property, or perhaps something like this (untested):

```
function equalObjects(o1, o2) {
    var okeys1 = Object.keys(o1);
    if (okeys1.length != Object.keys(o2).length)
        return false;
    for (var i = 0; i < okeys1.length; i++)
        if (o1[okeys1[i]] !== o2[okeys1[i]])
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

and then in my original function:

```
         if (equalObjects(array[i], item)) {
```

Comment: He will also be able to get the `array.remove(object)` syntax he wants by adding a similar function to `Array.prototype`.

Comment: @Matt - True. I'm not keen on modifying the prototype of built-in objects, so I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader...

Comment: I agree with you there... I was mainly leaving it as a hint the OP ;).

Answer (score 2):

I've made a mistake with this indexOf solution, but I'm correcting myself now:

```
function indexOf(arr, val, comparer) {
    for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; ++i) {
        if ( i in arr && comparer(arr[i], val) ) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

var index = indexOf(array,someObject, function(o1,o2) { return o1.id == o2.id && o1.color == o2.color; });
if (index > -1) {
    array.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AtGnY/5/

If you want to have it called this way: `array.remove(object)` then you can write this code like this:

```
Array.prototype.remove = function (object, comparer) {
    if (!comparer) {
        comparer = function (o1, o2) {
            return o1 === o2;
        };
    }
    var index = -1;
    for (var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; ++i) {
        if (i in this && comparer(this[i], object)) {
            index = i;
        }
    }

    if (index > -1) {
        array.splice(index, 1);
    }
};

array.remove(object, function (o1, o2) {
    return o1.id == o2.id && o1.color == o2.color;
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AtGnY/14/

Comment: This will not work. He has an array of objects, not of colours.

Comment: indexOf() will not take an object as a parameter, this must be a string so you'd have to put this through a loop first.

Comment: @Deryck - `.indexOf()` _will_ take an object, but this still won't work because `.indexOf()` uses strict equality so it would only remove the same _instance,_ not a duplicate object with properties set to the same values.

Comment: Mmm, this will still not work. The objects wont be `==` (let alone `===`) just because their keys hold the same values.

Comment: @nnnnnn haha good to know guess I needa find some more reputable sites to get this from

Comment: I've corrected my answer, you were right about standard indexOf, so I've found a solution with comparer.

Comment: @Deryck - MDN is pretty good. Just google "[any JS term here] mdn" and you'll be set.

Answer (score 0):

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-in-an-array-how-to-do-that-in-javascript)

That will at least give you access to the brute force method to solve your problem. Loop through the array and then compare each object.

[Find an object by ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-array-of-javascript-objects) is more compact and elegant, but may not match your needs.